# How to pass parameter with ui-sref between deeply nested objects?

Tags: angularjs, ui-sref

As i have nested object as follow:

**Provider(providerId) =>> Post (postId)=>> Comment (commentId)=>> Reply (replyId)**

So, while i am in the last step of reply i can not pass providerId into reply step.

Here is shown how works $stateParams in each steps.
[image]

Here is reply state.

```
$stateProvider
      .state('reply', {
        url: '/blog/providers/{providerId}/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}',
        templateUrl: 'app/blog/provider/post/comment/reply/reply.html',
        controller: 'ReplyCtrl'
      });
```

Therefore as i can not pass any parameter i am getting following error:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/api/providers//posts/5551b281bcaa20002387fb31/comments/5551b3b4bcaa20002387fb32 404 (Not Found)
```

This is what i have in comment.html, one step before reply in order to pass parameter to reply step. I am not sure how to retrieve providerId in this case as i don't have it here.

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments track by $index" >
.......
<a  ui-sref="reply({providerId: ..., postId : post._id, commentId: comment._id})"></a>
```

Also inside replyCtrl, i can not access to any of those variables where i have passed inside html and this is error i got. I simply added following lines inside replyCtrl.

```
console.log('postId from reply state' , postId);
console.log('commentId from reply state', commentId);
```

So this is my received error.

```
ReferenceError: postId is not defined
```

Is there any help in order to guide me how i pass parameter here.

Comment: Are you sure post._id and comment._id is correct? Have you looked at in batarang to see what the values are? In your example it doesn't look like that anchor is in the ng-repeat.

Comment: @EddieMongeJr Yes, post._id and comment._id were correct. Problem was with only providerId, which i didn't know how to pass it away. BTW, i solved that by passing providerId through $scope.provider = $stateParams.providerId . If there is any other way in order to pass parameter i will be thank you if you tell me. thx

Answer (score 0):

This link would help you :)

[Passing parameters in $stateProvider](https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-simple-tips-for-using-ui-router)